# How to select a row in kendogrid after filtering

Tags: select, filter, grid, row, kendo-ui

I have a kendogrid.  What I do is first filter it, which works fine.
After having it filtered, I want to select a specific row.  I am sure I have the row in the result of the filter.

Example:

```
data = id=a1, id=a2, id=a3, id=a4, id=a5, id=a6
```

filter result:

```
id=a2, id=a4, id=a6
```

I would like to select the row a4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all loop through the Grid's data which is currently displayed (i.e.

```
var arrayOfModels = $('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view();
```

next add the k-state-selected class to the row you want to make it selected

```
$('#GridName tbody [data-uid='+model.uid+']').addClass('.k-state-selected')
```

where *model* is the record from the arrayOfModels above which you need